# How to pretty print JSON with wp_json_encode()?

Tags: php, json, wordpress

wp_json_encode() prints the JSON string in one line. Can we make it pretty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of [wp_json_encode()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_json_encode/) [options](https://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php) parameter.

Setting options to `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` as an argument will make the function use whitespace in returned data to format it:

```
wp_json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```